# Mysqli return comma separated value in jquery not view that value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello every one i have small problem with my code where i can made mistake 
in jquery console.log(data); will show the value.

When that value return following error will display : The specified value "21,593" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression.

My Code jquery code is

```
$('#search-box<?=$x;?>').blur(function() {
         var val = $("#search-list<?=$x;?>").val();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "searchlist.php",
             data:'amount='+$(this).val(),
             success: (data) => {
               console.log(data);
             var number = $('#quantity<?=$x;?>').val();
             $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data); 
             var o_val = $("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(); 
             //console.log(o_val); 
             var op_val = number * o_val;
             //console.log(op_val);
             $("#amounta<?=$x;?>").val(op_val);
             var amount4_total = 0;
             for (var i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
               amount4_total += Number($(`#amounta${i}`).val());

               // console.log($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
             }
              //console.log(amount4_total);
          $('#amount4').val(amount4_total);
        // console.log($("#brand_val").val($('#amount4').val(amount4_total)));
         $("#brand_val").val(amount4_total);
             }
          });
           });
```

$("#unit_pricea").val(data); in this postion i will return value then the problem is occur.

My Screen Shots [here i will display the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph22n.jpg)

[here my console.log value and error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIP1Q.jpg)

Comment: `following regular expression` which is what?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you can see it in the picture, its a default warning message

Comment: @madalinivascu - i dislike image links.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix welcome to the club 

Comment: That wouldn't be the regex I would use, instead I would do this `-?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that is the default regex for a number field defined by the browser

Comment: hello every one my problem is mysqli database to value can return 21,538 and as it is value not display in jquery here i will place the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the thousand separator to get a valid JavaScript number

```
$("#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>").val(data.replace(',',''));
```

Comment: the amount on that filed is 24,390 but it will display 24.390 this way is not correct way

Comment: you mean the coma is the thousand separator ?then do  `data.replace(',','')`

Comment: thank u @madalinivascu but thousand separator not working in jquery

Comment: i will change . value to empty value. but i need that comma also like 12,538 but not working so that i will use empty value  and another question i will asking to u see this url :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533199/mysqli-id-value-can-assign-session-varible-but-alredy-session-started